# '[Errno 26] Text file busy: '/home/*****/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/83.0.4103.39/linux64/chromedriver''

Tags: python-3.x, linux, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

**Error while running selenium python code on linux VM '[Errno 26] Text file busy: '/home/*****/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/83.0.4103.39/linux64/chromedriver''**

I have running Selenium automated test of UI on every 1 hour through script on Linux VM but getting this error recently(from last 3-4 days),

```
'[Errno 26] Text file busy: '/home/*****/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/83.0.4103.39/linux64/chromedriver''
```

Can someone faced this error ever before, seems it said test file busy but before 3-4 days it was working properly with same script since beginning.(nothing has been change in script).

Is it error with OS-IO, if yes/no how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Try killing first the process and then run your selenium code:

```
kill -9 `pgrep -f home/xxxxx/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver`
```